Not able to access window object on the code loaded in vm.runIncontext() in jest , jsdom env
I'am working on project where we load all the commons files needed for testing via vm.runIncontext. when we are trying to access window object it throwing window is not defined error. This is working fine in node 16, but fails in node 18 and above.Please fine below the files.
**packge.json**
    {
      "name": "jsdom-tes",
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "main": "index.js",
      "scripts": {
        "test": "jest"
      },
      "author": "",
      "license": "ISC",
      "description": "",
      "devDependencies": {
        "jest": "^29.7.0",
        "jest-environment-jsdom": "^29.7.0"
      },
      "dependencies": {
        "jsdom": "^24.1.0"
      }
    }

Jest config file.
const config = {
testEnvironment: 'jsdom',
setupFilesAfterEnv: [ "<rootDir>/jestSetup.js"],
testMatch: ["<rootDir>/test/__test__/mytest.test.js"],
};

jest setup file
const vm = require('node:vm');
const fs = require( "fs" );

const ctx = vm.createContext(global);
ctx.hello = "helloworld";
ctx.window = "window";
const sContents = 'var a =1'


try {
  const result = vm.runInContext(`${sContents}; console.log(hello); console.log(window) `, ctx);
} catch(e) {
  console.log(e.stack, 'err1');
  console.log('x is', ctx.x)
}

  
  module.exports = config;

whenever I run this code in Node 20, im getting reference errors, working correctly in Node 16
evalmachine.<anonymous>:12
    ; console.log(hello); console.log(window) 
                                      ^
    
    ReferenceError: window is not defined

System:
    OS: macOS 14.5
    CPU: (12) arm64 Apple M3 Pro
  Binaries:
    Node: 20.14.0 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v20.14.0/bin/node
    npm: 10.7.0 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v20.14.0/bin/npm
  npmPackages:
    jest: ^29.7.0 => 29.7.0

Codesandbox- https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/x2p6ly?file=%2FjestSetup.js%3A17%2C2
Then in terminal/console, run the following commands
nvm use 20;
npm run test;

Ever find a solution?  I'm seeing this too!
